# Sharing RequestMapping spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I try to build a rest api with spring and face some issues. My original api is built with express on node and saw that some stuff I am pretty used to seem more complicated in spring.

For example, I have the following case, I could borrow the "controller" for `/tasks` even from the UserController.

```
/users
/users/:id
/users/:id/tasks
/tasks
```

Or I can easily inherit routes, my delegating them down. Spring doesn't seem to have something like that, where I could reference an already existing controller. It even seems to me that the RequestMapping value becomes long.

Is there something similar in Spring like what express can? Because I couldn't find any large spring mvc rest projects to illustrate that

Comment: Actually `@RequestMapping` supports multiple values. You can place all your paths strings in the mapping of UserController

Answer (score 0):

You could add multiple values for [`@RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) and also use `Path Variables` that fits your needs. For example,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}/tasks", method = GET)
public String getUserTaksFromIdPathVariable(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    return "Get all tasks from user with id=" + id;
}
```

And as I said, you can have multiple values:

```
@RequestMapping({"/tasks", "/users/{id}/tasks"}, method = GET)
public String getTasks(@PathVariable("id") Optional<long> id) {
    return "whatever";
}
```